# "WHERE IN" with strict compliance of matches

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose, we have table `room_human` for union `rooms`/`humans`. Need to get a `room` only contains concrete, certain `humans` and not another `human`. If you query rows with `human_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`, you can get `0-N` rows, including the `rooms` with other `humans`. Is there a way to select rows with strict compliance with the `IN` result? To get only 5 rows, only `rooms` contains concrete 5 `humans` (in example `IN (1,2,3,4,5)`)? I known, the problem can be solved in many ways, but i want 1 query. I think about an additional nested query, but... But suddenly I missed something simplest?

**update 1:** my one solution with a subquery:

```
SELECT a.room_id, COUNT(a.id) AS ac, c.bc
    FROM room_human a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(b.id) AS bc, b.room_id
        FROM room_human b
        WHERE b.human_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        GROUP BY b.room_id
    ) AS c ON c.room_id = a.room_id
    WHERE a.human_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY a.room_id
```

— expected result for example ac = 5, bc = NULL

**update 2:** i came up with a crazy solution:

```
SELECT rh.room_id, GROUP_CONCAT(rh.human_id ORDER BY rh.human_id) AS gc
FROM room_human rh
GROUP BY rh.room_id
HAVING gc='1,2,3,4,5';
```

— this grouping, but not nested query. But it is necessary to think.

Comment: Add table definitions, some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: In short: WUT?? "but i want 1 query" which is similar to the one you tried on the schema you show us?

Comment: @Pred , don't understand, what surprises you. This is not a difficult problem, but an interesting challenge. Solve with a subquery or 2 queries is easy, but there may be a simpler solution?

Comment: @jarlh this is a typical data structure: `human(id, ...)`, `room(id, ...)`, `room_human(room_id, human_id)`

Comment: @GennadyS you actually shown no effort and awaits for a query, aka you want us to do your work. I can do your work for you, but you have to hire me. StackOverflow is a QA site, not a code generation or debugger site. Is this a homework, or what?

Comment: @Pred I understand your claim. It's just an interesting challenge, and not a request for help. For someone maybe no one solutions. Then not allowed to question stackoverflow? I add my solution to question.

Comment: @GennadyS If it is just a challenge, do it in the right way, and don't use bad practice. Read the article about [ask] and modify your question. Post some sample code, maybe create an sqlfiddle or similar prepared environment, show your database structure. If this is a SQL challenge, then don't make it a reading challenge.

Comment: @Pred are you kidding me? This is a classic data structure is "_many to many_", and abstract question about lightweight, simplest solutions / possible operations of MySql. I could not think that specialists need clarification, say: `room (id, name, created_at)`, `human (id, age, name)`, `room_human(room_id, human_id)`, and more.

Comment: @GennadyS Which part sounds like a joke? Is the structure clear with a quick look? Nope, I have to guess it. You are simply lazy and now you are trying to save your reputation (with not much luck).

Comment: @Pred not right. I carefully wrote the question. But this is a classic data structure. This is just like what I did at job. I came up with table names on the go, this is not real data, these tables do not exist, this is abstract data structure `one`, `tho` and `one_tho` with `one_id` and `tho_id` for union. I never thought that you need to describe "many to many". I don't want a reputation, but solutions someone will be useful — to this end asked a question

Comment: I am not talking about the actual database constructs involved, I am talking about the format of the question and what it tells me. If you want to talk about the n:n relationship and how to handle it: if it is that easy, most probably this question is a dupe -> close it. If it is not that easy, then your question is not clear -> update or close it (yes, we have a close reason). Furthermore: you assume, that we will guess what you meant instead of executing a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and copy-paste the result. You don't have a clear statement about your problem -> wrong question.

Comment: @Pred why do you speak on behalt of everyone? **dasblinkenlight** give an instant answer! Therefore, you overstate. Really, first sentence of the question explains the elementary, basic data structure. I think this is your problem if you can not understand this question.

Comment: [ask] <- read it and the linked articles.

Comment: @Pred i'm sad from principle! This is a _typical_, _classic_, _basis_ data structure. There is nothing to explain. Question is good: explain the need for compliance rows with "WHERE IN (...)". _I understand the need to explain the problem_. If it is needed, i do not mind, and 1000 lines would be written, with code, with example data. But i right - _the question objectively exhaustive_. And you exaggerate aggressively.

Comment: Again, if it is that easy, most probably it is answered already -> you did not do the research -> the question is a dupe (unless there is a problem what is not solved yet) -> delete. I know what an n:n relationship is, I'm working with them on a daily basis. Your original question shows that you did nothing to solve the problem. This is what my first comment states: you did nothing, I do nothing. Show me, you want to solve this problem and not searching for somebody to solve it for you. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Pred i almost agree with you. But 1) this is an abstract question about the possible strategies, challenge, and not request assistance, help or work 2) i added the variant of solution on your request 3) in fact, all the necessary explanations ready to give. I asked for 10 minutes before the end of the job-day, because of interest :) I think anybody are just interested in the challenge, and not for the rankings or business approach.

Comment: 1) Then it is too broad for SO, your choice of QA site is wrong. 2) thanks, helps a lot. 3) if it is ready to give, why did not you give it? "I asked for 10 minutes before the end of the job-day" <- irrelevant information, "I think anybody are just interested in the challenge, and not for the rankings or business approach." <- this is not a challenge and it does not state, that there is no good answer, but just asks for opinions (which is not the scope of this site). How the rankings come in picture? (Would I talk to you instead of just writing a query if I am interested only in the rankings?)

Comment: @Pred the question is set out exhaustively. If you can not answer - go to answer the other questions. It's happens, it's normal — there are difficult questions (and there are questions with no solution or with no best solution). If you want to clarify something - i am ready to give an explanation. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: OK, so are you asking if the subquery + join, subquery in the where, subquery in the column list, `IN` with subquery, the `EXISTS` or a query with `HAVING` is better? It depends. Define 'better'. (Spoiler: I will say, it depends on lots of factors what we don't know, including the columns you want in the result, the distribution of values, the number of records, partitions on the tables if any, etc). If you know if there are lots of solutions, then tell us why they are not good for you, what extras you need.

Comment: @Pred query optimization is not specified in the question. Challenge only about how to do `WHERE IN` with strict compliance queried rows with "many to many" related rows, as if `WHERE IN (1, 2, 3)` would mean not _ONE OF_, but the equality of sets `WHERE id's = {1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: So how will you decide, which is the correct answer?

Comment: @Pred ofcourse, the one that does not contain nested queries, subqueries, or answer of professional in the fact that it is impossible otherwise. I wrote about this in question.

Comment: @Pred many years have passed, and I have thought many times, but I still haven't found a better solution :) This is a really interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other solutions not yet found:

```
SELECT rh.room_id
FROM room_human rh
GROUP BY rh.room_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(rh.human_id ORDER BY rh.human_id)='1,2,3,4,5';
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be using an additional `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM room_human t
WHERE t.human_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM room_human o
    WHERE o.room_id=t.room_id
      AND o.human_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
  )
```

Since you are interested in rooms that have a single occupant, another approach is to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT MIN(human_id), room_id
FROM room_human
WHERE human_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
GROUP BY room_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```